# Game of cards numbered from $1$ to $10$

Tags: probability

There are $10$ cards, labeled from $1$ to $10$. The probability that the cards denoted by $a, b, c (a > b > c)$ are drawn from the
cards at the same time is $1/k$ where $$\int_{0}^{a} (x^2 − 2bx + 3c)dx=0$$, then find $k$

How should I proceed in this question. On solving integral we get $a^2-3ab+9c=0$ but how should we use it to find probability.

Comment: This is hard to follow.  That integral hasn't got a $k$ in it.  Also, you integrated it incorrectly.

Comment: As far as I can sort out, you are saying that there is some probability distribution on the set of ordered triples taken from $\{1,\cdots, 10\}$.  There are $\binom {10}3=120$ such triples so you need to specify $120$ probabilities that add to $1$.  Clearly, there are many ways to do that, so you need some constraints.  What constriants do you have?

Comment: @lulu Question asks us to find probability which will be $1/40$ as answer given is $k=40$. $k$ is not related to integral

Comment: If $k$ is unrelated to the integral, why did you provide the integral?

Comment: Are you supposed to find integer solutions $a>b>c$ to the integral? One solution is $a=3$, $b=2$, $c=1$. Each solution has probability $\frac{1}{\binom{10}{3}}=\frac{1}{120}$ of being chosen, so you should try to show there are three solutions.

Comment: @lulu I think the question is "Find the probability that cards denoted by $a,b,c(a<b<c)$" are drawn so that given integral$=0$

Comment: @kccu Yes that is the question as per my understanding too.

Comment: Well, the only solutions in the range are $(3,2,1)$, $(6,3,2)$ , $(9,4,3)$ by simple search.